# Confidence interval for combined populations

Tags: confidence-interval, binomial-distribution, standard-error, bernoulli-distribution, pooling

I'd like to compare two approaches for calculating the confidence interval ($CI$) when estimating the mean for a sample of weighted values:

The first approach is based upon the standard error of the mean itself ($\hat{x}$):

$$
CI_{(1-\alpha)} = \hat{x} \pm t_{(\alpha/2, df)} * s / \sqrt{n}
$$

The second is based upon the standard error of a proportion:

$$
CI_{(1-\alpha)} = \hat{p} \pm t_{(\alpha/2, df)} * \sqrt{\hat{p} * (1 - \hat{p}) / n}
$$

The tricky part (for me) is how to combine the standard error of the weighted proportions into a population.

Consider an example: If we start with a random sample of 50 coins taken from a jar (without replacement):

| qty | denomination | value ($w$) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 15 | pennies | \$0.01 |
| 7 | nickels | \$0.05 |
| 8 | dimes | \$0.10 |
| 20 | quarters | \$0.25 |

Incorporating the value (or weights) of each coin's denomination into a weighted mean for all coins is trivial. The combined value of the 50-coin sample is \$6.25, so the weighted mean of a coin is \$0.1250. The standard deviation is $0.1069, so the confidence interval is \$[0.0946, 0.1554].

Alternatively, we can look at the sample as the aggregate of four populations (i.e., the four denominations of coins) and calculate $CI$s for those individual populations:

| denomination | proportion | confidence interval |
| --- | --- | --- |
| pennies | 0.3000 | [0.1698, 0.4302] |
| nickels | 0.1600 | [0.0558, 0.2642] |
| dimes | 0.1400 | [0.0414, 0.2386] |
| quarters | 0.4000 | [0.2608, 0.5392] |

A brute-force way to pool these intervals would be to combine them in ways that maximized proportions of low- and high-value coins. E.g., to establish a lower bound, I could combine 43.02% pennies, 26.42% nickels, 4.48% dimes, and 26.08% quarters. For the upper bound, I could combine 16.98% pennies, 5.58% nickels, 23.52% dimes, and 53.92% quarters. The combinations for both the lower and upper bounds will add up to 100%.

I'm not sure that approach captures all available information, however.

What is the formula to pool the standard error for *weighted* proportions? Intuition suggests that pooling the standard error for multiple proportions introduces more uncertainty, but I'd like to confirm/refute that with the appropriate formula.

Comment: Why take this approach at all?  Why not directly analyze the values themselves in the usual way?

Comment: Thanks, @whuber. I agree that it'd be straightforward to calculate a confidence interval for the mean. However, coins have discrete values, so the sampling distribution of the mean is actually truncated normal. In extreme cases (i.e., when _most_ of the coins are pennies or quarters), the bounds of the CI for the mean will return impossible values (i.e., lb < 0.01 or ub > 0.25). While I could likewise truncate the confidence interval, I'd prefer to use the sampled proportions of coins to avoid having to deal with the messiness of a truncated normal sampling distribution for the mean.

Comment: The sampling distribution of the mean is *never* exactly Normal.  In your case, it is exceptionally close to Normal and the usual Normal-theory methods give optimal results.

Comment: Thanks again, @whuber. I've reframed the question to (hopefully) focus less on the example and more on the concept that I'm trying to better understand.